# Count unique values in column A for each unique value in column B

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For Example:

```
Column A - Student Names
Column B - Classes Registered (possible classes: "History","Geology","Biology")
Column C - Semester (ex: S12015,S22016.etc)
```

I want to be able to define three formulas for three different cells elsewhere so I can get the number of students who registered for History, Geology and Biology at least once.

Is it possible to generalize this to output the grouped counts to two different columns, say:

```
Column D: Name of Class
Column E: Number of students registered in the class at least once
```

EDIT:

Updated my Post with Column C. That fully states my problem. I am able to get an answer by following a similar case here: http://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/07/12/count-unique-distinct-values-that-meet-multiple-criteria-in-excel/

Comment: You've definitely been here long enough to know you have to show effort.

Comment: @findwindow - I am a novice when it comes to excel formulas, I did try to get a solution by a combination of COUNTIF, MATCH and FREQUENCY, only to realize that I do not really know the basics to even start to solve it. Didn't want to advertise my lack of basic knowledge

Comment: What's wrong with the [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) / [COUNTIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) functions?

Comment: but if you show us your efforts, we can definitely help you more. Instead of "advertising you're lack of knowledge" you are showing us how you are trying to learn / accomplish your goal. Also, if you provide a bit more realistic sample data it will help

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of unique classes use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$15,MATCH(1,IF(COUNTIF($C$1:$C1,$B$1:$B$15)=0,1,0),0)),"")
```

Being an array formula, it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode. If done properly Excel will automatically put `{}` around the formula, indicating an array formula.

then to find the count a simple COUNTIF():

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$15,C2)>0,COUNTIF($B$1:$B$15,C2),"")
```

Then copy down far enough to ensure that all the unique classes are found.

[image]

One caveat, The larger the data list and formula list the longer it will take to calculate.